# Entab program unexpected error (read acess violation)

Tags: c, access-violation

I used debugger to find my bug. And i was able to find what the bug is. But i do not know why is it occurring. The bug is that `linep` becames some junky adress after 1 `push` is done (1 space is added). So at the second `push` it gives me an error on this line: `tmp1 = tmp2 = *x;` because `linep` is some junky adress (i guess). I do not know why `linep` becomes junky adress. I hope someone can explain that. Here is the code:

Note: The program's purpose is to replace every tab with 4 spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINESIZE 1000
#define TABSPACES 4

void push(char *x, char val, int index);
int mgetline(char *s, int lim);

int main(void) {
    char line[MAXLINESIZE];
    char *linep = line;
    while (mgetline(line, MAXLINESIZE) > 0) {
        while (*linep) {
            if (*linep == '\t') {
                *linep = ' ';
                for (int i = 1; i <= TABSPACES - 1; i++) {
                    push(line, ' ', linep - line + 1);
                    linep++;
                }
            }
            linep++;
        }
        printf("%s", line);
        linep = line;
    }
    return 0;
}

void push(char *x, char val, int index) {
    char tmp1, tmp2, cnt;
    char *ptc;
    x += index - 1;
    ptc = x;
    tmp1 = tmp2 = *x;
    cnt = 0;
    while (tmp2) {
        tmp2 = *x;
        *x = tmp1;
        tmp1 = *(x + 1);
        *(x + 1) = tmp2;
        x += 2;
        cnt++;
    }
    *ptc = val;
}

int mgetline(char *s, int lim)
{
    int c;
    char *t = s;

    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        *s++ = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        *s++ = c;

    *s = '\0';

    return s - t;
}
```

Note: In input `.` is equal to tab (09 hexadecimal ASCII CODE) and `*` is equal to space (20 hexadecimal ASCII CODE).

Input:

> a.b.c.d*e.f**.g****h.j*.k**l

Comment: You cannot make the line longer in-place. You can filter out characters and make it shorter, but not the other way round, because the insertion pointer will overtake the source pointer and destory the road before you. It may even frog-leap the null terminator.

Comment: You must also reset `linep` to the start of `line` for every line you read. At the moment, you do that only once at thze beginning, outside the line-reading loop.

Comment: Okay, you push the whole line to the right when you insert a space. This is very inefficient and also bears the risk that the text is pushed into illegal territory at the right end. Why don't you keep two separate lines, one for input, one for output? Or just print to the output stream immediately without an intermeidate string, which always has the risk of buffer overrun?

Comment: And your `push` function is too complicated. I don't think you need all these variables. It's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @MOehm Its hard to see what you write in comments. Could you make an answer? If you found the bug. And i did not understand your first comment. By the way, i know the code is bad but, i dont want to change it. I just want to fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the loop to copy the pointer properly into a new buffer that will allow the spaces to be put into the string without overwriting the actual input. You need to ensure that the extra spaces do not overflow the line. You also need to make sure that the EOL has been put in.

Assuming push works, then you are in effect pushing the line to the right which risks overrunning the max size of the line array. You also do not return the new pointer which means that you will test the extra spaces as well as moving the entire contents of the line array every single time. You are better off handling it as an input and output line separately.

If you insist on using your push code, then make line long enough to allow the extra spaces to be inserted as well as adding `linep = line;` inside the loop. Calculate the original line size (using strlen()), increment it by the total number of spaces added, and test to ensure that it does not overflow the array (which would be set to be greater than MAXLINESIZE). Return the new pointer (after the spaces) from push so that you do not check all the spaces that you have added in your loop.

I would suggest not trying to "fix" the code, but redo it to be more efficient. I will show your original code with comments pointing out the bugs after I show my suggestions.

```
int main(void) {
    char line[MAXLINESIZE];
    char *linep = line;
    char newline[MAXLINESIZE];
    char *newlinep = newline;
    while (mgetline(line, MAXLINESIZE) > 0) {
        linep = line;
        newlinep = newline;
        while (*linep) {
            if (*linep == '\t') {
                for (int i = 0; i <= TABSPACES - 1; i++) {
                    *newlinep = ' ';
                    newlinep++;
                }
                if ((newlinep - &newline) >= MAXLINESIZE) {
                    printf("Line filled, need to stop");
                    newlinep = &newline[MAXLINESIZE-1];
                    break;
            }
            else {
                *newlinep = *linep;
                newlinep++;
            }
            linep++;
        }
        *newlinep = '\0'
        printf("%s", newline);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is your original code with my comments as to what needs to be changed

```
char *push(char *x, char val, int index);
int mgetline(char *s, int lim);

int main(void) {
    // Make line big enough to hold the extra spaces
    char line[3*MAXLINESIZE];
    char *linep = line;
    while (mgetline(line, MAXLINESIZE) > 0) {
        // You need to reset the line pointer here
        linep = line;
        while (*linep) {
            if (*linep == '\t') {
                *linep = ' ';
                for (int i = 1; i <= TABSPACES - 1; i++) {
                    // Return the pointer to put after the spaces
                    // You also need to test to avoid overrun
                    linep = push(line, ' ', linep - line + 1);
                }
            }
            linep++;
        }
        printf("%s", line);
        linep = line;
    }
    return 0;
}

char * push(char *x, char val, int index) {
    // You need to check to make sure you do not overrun x.
    char tmp1, tmp2, cnt;
    char *ptc;
    x += index - 1;
    ptc = x;
    tmp1 = tmp2 = *x;
    cnt = 0;
    while (tmp2) {
        tmp2 = *x;
        *x = tmp1;
        tmp1 = *(x + 1);
        *(x + 1) = tmp2;
        x += 2;
        cnt++;
    }
    *ptc = val;
    return ptc;
}
```

Comment: Yea. This should work. But i wanted a repair (e.g. finding the bug) to my code, not a new one.

Comment: @Siliproksi Assuming push works, then you are in effect pushing the line to the right which risks overrunning the max size of the line array. You also do not return the new pointer which means that you will test the extra spaces as well as moving the entire contents of the line array every single time. You are better off handling it as an input and output line separately.

Comment: Turth. Porbably, i will. But firstly i will try to find the bug in this code.

Comment: @Siliproksi I pointed out the bugs in your code - linep not reset at the beginning of the loop, line set too small, and you do not test for overrunning the line buffer.